# ScriptBundle Reference missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am building a MVC 3 application. I just added a ADO.NET entity data model.
When i try to build the solution, it gives the following error

> > ***The type or namespace name 'ScriptBundle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)***

I already have reference to Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.
Please help...

Comment: And what about the `using` directive?

Comment: Ya, i have added using System.Web.Optimization

Comment: Moreover, this happens only when I build a MVC 3 Empty application. While using an Internet application (which already contains Home & About pages), it runs without any error.

Answer (score 3):

Did you installed it from NuGet package manager? I think that is the reason you are facing the issue

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
```

Comment: Yup. It shows Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization already referenced.